# How to make Chrome extension to capture user mic input along with tabcapture input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I am trying to build extension for school project to capture meeting audio+video

currently i am exploring the code https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/screen_capture/#audio-and-video-offscreen-doc
The main problem that I am facing is to record user mic audio , it's only recoding tab audio
can anyone help me to modify the code to take user mic input aswell?

In your service worker:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {
  const existingContexts = await chrome.runtime.getContexts({});

  const offscreenDocument = existingContexts.find(
    (c) => c.contextType === 'OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT'
  );

  // If an offscreen document is not already open, create one.
  if (!offscreenDocument) {
    // Create an offscreen document.
    await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
      url: 'offscreen.html',
      reasons: ['USER_MEDIA'],
      justification: 'Recording from chrome.tabCapture API',
    });
  }

  // Get a MediaStream for the active tab.
  const streamId = await chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId({
    targetTabId: tab.id
  });

  // Send the stream ID to the offscreen document to start recording.
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'start-recording',
    target: 'offscreen',
    data: streamId
  });
});
```

offscreen document:

```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message) => {
      if (message.target !== 'offscreen') return;
      
      if (message.type === 'start-recording') {
        const media = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: {
            mandatory: {
              chromeMediaSource: "tab",
              chromeMediaSourceId: message.data,
            },
          },
          video: {
            mandatory: {
              chromeMediaSource: "tab",
              chromeMediaSourceId: message.data,
            },
          },
        });
    
        // Continue to play the captured audio to the user.
        const output = new AudioContext();
        const source = output.createMediaStreamSource(media);
        source.connect(output.destination);
    
        // TODO: Do something to recording the MediaStream.
      }
    });
```

I have managed to take user mic permision through option.js

```
document.getElementById('requestPermission').addEventListener('click', () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
     .catch(err => {
        alert('Error: ' + err);
      });
  });
```

Comment: look  at for this video this explain how to record tab and screen  from extension  broswer

Comment: @Risk which video ?

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/main/functional-samples/sample.tabcapture-recorder/service-worker.js